# Why do I get this optimizing tip in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

In Google Play one of my apps gets this warning in optimizing tips:

Your APK needs to meet the following criteria:
Uses available screen space on 7" tablets.

I have read the documentation and don't see what I'm doing wrong. If I look on the APK details in the Developer Console it says that 4 screen layouts are supported (small, normal, large, xlarge).

My manifest file is quite simple with this uses-sdk:

```
<uses-sdk
  android:minSdkVersion="7"
  android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I had created a simple dummy application with pretty much the same manifest-file, and that application doesn't get this warning. I'm confused :-). Is there anything more I need to declare tablet support?

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your manifest:

```
  <supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="true" />
```

However this:

> Your APK needs to meet the following criteria: Uses available screen space on 7" tablets.

refers to something else. I assume, that the developer console checked your app structure and found out, that you aren't using `layout-sw600dp` or `layout-sw720dp` etc. folders to optimize your layouts for tablets.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply :-). I have consider using supports-screens tag, but that doesn't seem to be needed according to the documentation. And my dummy-application don't need that so I think something else is problem. My real application does in fact uses values-sw500dp for some layouts. I have tried with values-sw500dp in my dummy application but that doesn't have any affect.

Comment: I contacted the support for this issue. The actually answered with this: "Upon further review, we have determined that your application does not meet the basic tablet app quality checklist to be considered designed for use on tablet devices as explained here: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html" I’m not really sure what the meant :-(. Could it be that someone manually have determined that it’s not well designed enough? I’m really confused :-(.

Comment: Your link doesn't work in your last comment @user1883479 ... please remove the " off the end!!

Comment: I’m sorry about that. For some reason I can’t edit my comment anymore, so I provide the correct link here instead: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/quality/tablet.html

Comment: Google might also be analyzing your screenshots to see if there's too much whitespace or large areas in a single color.

Answer (score 0):

From everything I've been able to glean, it's likely triggered by excessive whitespace in your layouts.  It appears that Google has some algorithm that generates a screen layout and if more than X% is whitespace on a tablet it says it's not tablet optimized.  What X% is I couldn't begin to say.